# what is the R code to calculated a mean and standard deviation of multiple mean and standard deviations?

Tags: r, mean, standards, deviation

what is the R code to calculated a mean and standard deviation of multiple mean and standard deviations? each has its own number of items...

I tried to search online and in this forum but there was no straight answer...thank you!

Comment: just use `mean(x)` and `sd(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to provide us with an example?

The R code to calculate a mean is

```
mean()
```

So for example if you had a set of numbers

```
values <- c(0, 4, 23, 4, 5)
mean(values)
[1] 7.2
```

You could nest `mean()` if you'd like

```
values <- c(mean(c(0, 15, 10)), mean(c(100, 4)))
mean(values)
[1] 30.16667
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot do `mean(0,15, 10)` you should do `mean(c(0,10,15))`

Answer (score 0):

If you have several means (lets call them `a` and `b)` and their corresponding standard deviations (lets call them `sa`and `sb`) and you calculated the mean of means (via `mean(c(a,b))`) then you need to do "error propagation" for the corresponding standard deviation. In this case the new standard deviation `sab` would be: `sab=1/2*sqrt(sa^2+sb^2)`